# cabal-installing hopenssl on Windows

Tags: haskell, openssl, cabal

I'm attempting to cabal install hopenssl on windows and receiving this error (see below)

Note: I do have openssl installed on windows, and have evp.h in the path

> C:/Users/username/Desktop/src/openssl/0.9.8h/openssl-0.9.8h/outinc/openssl/

Why isn't cabal recognizing the path on install?

```sh
$ cabal install hopenssl \
  --extra-include-dirs=C:/Users/username/Desktop/src/openssl/0.9.8h/openssl-0.9.8h/outinc/openssl/ \
  --extra-lib-dirs=C:/Users/username/Desktop/src/openssl/0.9.8h/openssl-0.9.8h/outinc/openssl/

cabal.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:

* Missing (or bad) header file: openssl/evp.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
hopenssl-1.6.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: What happens if you put those flags before the `hopenssl` in `cabal install hopenssl`?  You could also try downloading the source manually and setting up the extra lib paths in the `.cabal` file, then just using `cabal install`.

Comment: @bheklilr same story :/, I tried specifying the paths manually in the cabal file. I'm attempting to reinstall openssl libs through cygwin

Comment: @dave - to build FFI bindings on Windows you should use MinGW + MSys rather than Cygwin.

Comment: @stephentetley thank you for the advice, I'm running into further issues trying to install hsopenssl (not to be confused with hopenssl), and am now trying mingw and msys. I have installed every bin and dev I can, still no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: @stephentetley nevermind got that working too. cabal install hsopenssl --extra-include-dirs="C:/OpenSSL-Win32/outinc" --extr a-lib-dirs="C:/OpenSSL-Win32"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got hopenssl installed on Windows (32-bit) by doing the following:

- Download the latest version of Cygwin (`setup-x86.exe`) from http://www.cygwin.com/
- Go through the installation process as normal, but search for openssl when it comes to the 'Selecting packages' part, and install those libs.
- Create a Cygwin shortcut on your desktop
- Open cygwin, create a sandbox in a new directory: `cabal sandbox init`
- cabal install hopenssl

If all goes well, you should see the following output below:

```
$ cabal install hopenssl
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring hopenssl-1.6.2...
Building hopenssl-1.6.2...
Preprocessing library hopenssl-1.6.2...
[1 of 3] Compiling OpenSSL.Digest   ( OpenSSL\Digest.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-fef81833\build\OpenSSL\Digest.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling OpenSSL.Digest.ByteString ( OpenSSL\Digest\ByteString.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-fef81833\build\OpenSSL\Digest\ByteString.o )
[3 of 3] Compiling OpenSSL.Digest.ByteString.Lazy ( OpenSSL\Digest\ByteString\Lazy.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-fef81833\build\OpenSSL\Digest\ByteString\Lazy.o )
In-place registering hopenssl-1.6.2...
Installing library in
C:\cygwin\home\cspp\test\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\hopenssl-1.6.2
Registering hopenssl-1.6.2...
Installed hopenssl-1.6.2
```